# HTML Frames - server-side load or client side load

Tags: html, frame

I know HTML Frames are kinda deprecated, but I have a question, lets say if I load `www.google.com` in an html frame in my webpage. Will that be loaded at server side and the result will be sent to me or will that be loaded on the client side by the client after the page had browser has loaded and rendered the frame?

Comment: As you have `HTML` in your tags you answer yourself the question. HTML is parsed client-side, so it would be impossible for something within HTML to be server-side (this includes iframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be loaded clientside. The server only serves the html with the frameset and then the client loads each frame seperatly like any other page.